# Как увидеть конфликтные файлы

Tags: git, git-merge

### Проблема:

- Делая `git merge` получил конфликт на 168 файлов, регуляркой исправил больше половины. Но нужно узнать что не получилось починить. Обычная команда `git diff` показывает все изменненные файлы, и не видно что нужно еще подправить.

### Что нужно:

- Найти класную команду в `git` которая покажет мне только те файлы которые нужно еще подправить.

### Что пробовал:

- `git diff --name-status` думал что у неисправленные файлы должны иметь особый статус, но оба варианта показывают как `U` и `M`
- `git status -sb` показывает просто файлы которые еще не в индексе

### Примеры:

- `git diff not-resolved.file` показывает примерно такое

  ```
  git diff
  diff --cc hello.rb
  index 0399cd5,59727f0..0000000
  --- a/hello.rb
  +++ b/hello.rb
  @@@ -1,7 -1,7 +1,11 @@@
    #! /usr/bin/env ruby

    def hello
  ++<<<<<<< HEAD
   +  puts 'hola world'
  ++=======
  +   puts 'hello mundo'
  ++>>>>>>> mundo
    end

    hello()
  ```
- `git diff resolved.file` показывает особыми палочками как был решен конфликт

  ```
  $ git diff
  diff --cc hello.rb
  index 0399cd5,59727f0..0000000
  --- a/hello.rb
  +++ b/hello.rb
  @@@ -1,7 -1,7 +1,7 @@@
    #! /usr/bin/env ruby

    def hello
  -   puts 'hola world'
   -  puts 'hello mundo'
  ++  puts 'hola mundo'
    end

    hello()
  ```

### Размышления:

- с примеров видно что git точно видет разницу между этими файлами, тоесть он их видимо как то пометил.
- возможно задача вообще нерешаемая, может git просто при выводе смотрит что отсуствует "++<<<<<<< HEAD" и декорирует вывод по другому с учетом состояния theirs и ours версии
- если git как то помечает исправленные файлы, то как бы она пометила файл в ктором 2 кофликта, и один был исправлен а другой нет
- с примеров видно что

  - `+` обозначает что строка пришла с предедущей версии и досих пор
    присуствует в файле
  - `-` обозначет что пришло с предедущей версии но уже не присуствует в файле
  - `++` обозначет что строка присуствует только в новом файле.
- печально но пока что самый надежный вариант это `grep -H -r "<<<<<<< HEAD" .`
- git не просто так делает маркеры начала и конца конфликта "<<<<<<< HEAD", может отсуствие этих маркеров подсказывают ему что возможно решен конфликт, и можно без grep-а узнать это

Comment: возможно, эту работу поможет сделать ``grep -Hw "<<<<<<<" ./``, если усовершенствовать: ``find ~/path/to/project -name "pattern" | grep -w "<<<<<<<"``.

Comment: @LXA логично, но думаю настолько что в git могли бы это уже добавить под какой нибудь опцией :)

Comment: *с примеров видно что git точно видет разницу между этими файлами, тоесть он их видимо как то пометил.* Исходя из чего Вы сделали такой вывод? Я ничего такого в Ваших примерах не заметил.

Comment: @PetSerAl чем больше размышляю тем бошльше прихожу к выводу что git не видет между ними разницу :(. Но всеравно надеюсь на волшебную опцию

Comment: @LXA делай ответ, я думаю что твой вариант оказался единственным рабочим

Comment: git mergetool пробовали?

Comment: @tonal пробовал но не разобрался, мне кажеться что она просто проксирует решение конфликта во внешнюю утилиту, но пока не вижу чем она может помочь

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs grep '<<<<<<< HEAD'`
для bash можно просто получить все unmerged файлы и отфилтровать те которые содежат HEAD

Answer (score 4):

Решение на powershell:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | get-item |? { select-string '<<<<<<< HEAD' $_ }
```

Идея простая - получаем список файлов в состоянии unmerged и ищем осталась ли в них строка *"<<<<<<< HEAD"*.

Comment: Может распишите в чём тут дело? Чтобы те, кому PS не подходит могли бы легко это переписать на что-то другое.

Comment: @ixSci написал.

Comment: у меня в bash это вывалилось ошибкой (синтаксическая ошибка лексемы `(`), Но если я правильно понял идею, но не виже чем это улчше `grep -H -r "<<<<<<< HEAD" .`

Comment: @duhon это лучше тем, что сканируются не все-все-все файлы, который может быть очень много - а только те, в которых были замечены конфликты.

Comment: тоесть на bash это будет примерно такое  `git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U | xargs grep '<<<<<<< HEAD'`

Comment: @duhon да. Спасибо за команду, кстати. Ее и в powershell использовать можно

Comment: @PavelMayorov добавьте ее в ответ как альтернативу powershell, и я приму этот ответ, думаю волшебного параметра для git уже не будет

Comment: @duhon э... почему альтернатива-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov алтернатива потому что не у всех есть powershell. Тоесть в маке и линуксе есть bash, а на винде powershell. Поэтому я думаю будет удобно в одном ответе 2 варианта для разных шелов.

Comment: @duhon но это не будет моим ответом

Comment: @duhon я думаю, вам стоит написать свой ответ

Answer (score -1):

поставить intellij  и делать мердж там, мердж с конфликтами - это интерактивный процесс и cli-инструменты для него абсолютно непригодны.
можете поставить плагины для vim, если у вас нет GUI/Java,

честно говоря, meld/qdiff/raw git diff  очень проигрывают инструментам мерджа intellij.

Comment: прикольно то что я делаю мердж в intellij, который мне помог по регулярке решить много конфликтов одним махом, но git add он не делает. И когда я прошу показать что в конфликте, он показывает все unmerged файлы.

Comment: хотел добавить что за git в нем отвечает плагин "git integration" 1.8

Comment: я мерджу в intellij, делаю git add/commit/push в консоли. возможно все из-за того, что у меня коммерческие версии (phpstorm/pycharm/clion) может быть в  бесплатных плагин как-то обрезан (если проверите в триалках, будет интересно)

Comment: :) в данный момент я использую коммерческую версию phpstorm, так что я думаю у нас одинаковые версии 2016 года. В триалках огринчение по времени использования без урезания функционала. Можете проверить, сделать у себя конфликт одного файла, потом исправить его руками, а потом попросить Intellij показать какие файлы нужно исправить. Уверено что тотже самый один файл

Comment: ну короче я огромнейшие мерджи на больших кодовых базах там проводил, не знаю, как вы вообще вьехали туда (ну кроме того факта, что иногда шторм может сглюкнуть и оставить ошметки мерджа)

Comment: @duhon *сделать у себя конфликт одного файла, потом исправить его руками, а потом попросить Intellij показать какие файлы нужно исправить.* Тут собственно возникает вопрос: как Intellij (или любая другая программа) может узнать, что Вы **закончили** разрешение конфликта? Может быть, конфликт ещё не решён, и надо дописать ещё пару строк, чтобы его решить. Вы не пометили конфликт как решённый (`git add`), поэтому для меня естественно, что Intellij продолжит показывать данный конфликт.

Comment: @PetSerAl я абсолютно согласен, просто поступил ответ что intellij все сделает, вот я и уточнял как это можно решить с помощью GUI. Может быть она вызывает `grep -H -r "<<<<<<< HEAD" .` в любом случае еще нужно делать commit, где можно будет все перепроверить.

Comment: @duhon, там же графический интерфейс есть. Хорошо работает, хотя поначалу 3 панели кажутся непривычными.